# Most efficient way to retrieve "top x" records using Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

We've gotten a report request in, and I'm trying to find out the easiest and most efficient way to pull the numbers.

I have a *Deal*  model with two attributes: _quantity_purchased_ and *price*.  I've been asked to retrieve a list of the top 100 best selling deals in the database.  To see how well a deal has done, we multiply the quantity_purchased by the price.

Now, I'm sure I could write something convoluted to get my results, but this seems like such a simple operation, that there has got to be an easier way of doing it.  Is there something I could do in MySQL, or using Ruby/Rails?  Or am I stuck finding some kind of unpleasant loop?

FYI, we are running Rails 2.3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass a `:limit` parameter to your `find` method to limit the number of results returned. Combined with a `:order` parameter, you can get the 'top' 100 results:

```
Deal.find(:all, :order => 'quantity_purchased * price', :limit => 100);
```

Note as of Rails 3, the correct way of writing this query would be

```
Deal.order('quantity_purchased * price').limit(100)
```

Comment: The problem is that I have to perform some math to get the "top" results.  To calculate how much revenue a deal has made, I have to multiply quantity_purchased by the price.  A deal that only sold 5, may have made more money than one that sold 50.

Comment: @Kevin you can perform the math in the `:order` clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :top_deals, :select => 'quantity_purchased * price', :order => '1 DESC', :limit => 100
end
```

That should do it. In MySQL you can use "ORDER BY 1" to sort by the first column in the select list and so on.